# Save predefined custom follow-up intents in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to save predefined custom follow-up intents in Dialogflow? Say I have a custom intent that can be used in multiple places as a followup, it would be nice to be able to create it once and then select it directly from the dropdown list instead of creating a new one with the same training phrases every time.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Even better than using Followup Intents in this case would be to use [Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview). (Followup Intents just use Contexts under the hood anyway).

In this scheme, for every Intent where you might want a specific set of replies to be considered and handled in the same way, you would set an Output Context. You may want to set a short lifespan for the Context (Dialogflow sets it to 5 by default, but 2 when it makes a Followup Intent).

Then, for those Intents where you only want them to be considered when the Context is valid, set this as the Input Context for the Intent.

If you need the same Intent for several Contexts, one approach is to not specify the Input Context, but rather examine if the Context is valid in your Fulfillment. If it is - handle it appropriately, while if not, handle it the same way you handle your Fallback Intent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not exactly sure it solved my problem though because in my case, I'm hoping to reuse the same followup intent for multiple input contexts (e.g., saying generically "I don't know" in various input contexts) but according to this [document](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/how-contexts-and-followup-intents-work/) (and my own testing), "an intent will only be matched if *all* of the input contexts it specifies are currently active." Is there a way to trigger an intent as long as when *one* of the input contexts is met?

Comment: Just to provide more context: I understand I can simply duplicate this follow-up intent for each of the input contexts, but I just feel that it is not very "clean" (not to mention that I'll need to supply the same training phrases to each of them). Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think I can do that.